# How to convert a set variable to/from byte/file/inputstream/string?

Tags: java, string, set, byte, blob

I am trying to store a set containing some data into a `blob` (in cloud storage like `Rackspace CloudFiles` or `Amazon S3`)

Now, this is the code used to actually store the set variable into the cloud provider(using `jclouds` library) -

```
Set<? extends NodeMetadata> nodes;
BlobStore blobStore = bscontext.getBlobStore();
Blob blob;
```

The `blob` has to be stored/retrieved to/from the cloud storage. These are the following ways to actually store some data in the blob -

```
 blob.setPayload(argument)
 Argument= byte/file/inputstream/string.
```

What I want to know is, which of the above do I use (i.e. byte or file or inputstream or string)? Also, how do I convert the value stored in Set variable named 'nodes' into that format, so that I can store it as a `blob`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do any of the above.  I suggest you do what you believe is simplest.  You can store it as text/string with XMLEncoder or XStream as XML or JSon.  You can store the data is binary with ObjectOutputStream or something like protobuf,